# Using array of indices to define folds in GridSearchCV when the input is a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `GridSearchCV` to perform the model selection using custom indices in order to define the folds. Everything works as expected when the input is a `numpy` array as in the example below

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X = np.random.rand(100, 10)
y = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 100)
custom_split = [(list(range(80)), list(range(80, 100))), (list(range(90)), list(range(90, 100)))]

gs_cv = GridSearchCV(SGDClassifier(), param_grid = {'loss': ['log', 'modified_huber']}, cv=custom_split)
gs_cv.fit(X, y)
```

Instead if the input is a `pandas` data frame I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd

X_df = pd.DataFrame(X)
gs_cv.fit(X_df, y)
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'flags'

I need to use the data frame and I cannot switch to the array, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `X_df.values`?

Comment: Because in the real scenario I have a pipeline with custom transformers that expect data frame as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PredefinedSplit` to solve this issue.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit

X = np.random.rand(100, 10)
y = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 100)
test_folds = [-1] * 80 + [0] * 10 + [1] * 10
ps = PredefinedSplit(test_folds)

gs_cv = GridSearchCV(SGDClassifier(), param_grid = {'loss': ['log', 'modified_huber']}, cv=ps)
gs_cv.fit(pd.DataFrame(X), y)
```